# multiple expression if else within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="book in books">
<a href="#/{{book.title}}"> <h3 class="title">{{book.title}}</h3></a>
</div>
```

I use above code to get and it work fine, but I also have a search function, which will also set `$scope.books`. Unfortuunetly I have no control over the api, the search callback returned different scheme, means to get the title of the books I have to navigate to somewhere else, like `book.category.item.title`.

so I'm thinking of doing something like this

```
<a href="#/{{book.title || book.category.item.title}}">
```

check if book.title isset, else display another expression. Is it correct?

Comment: Use [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) when you want dynamic URL's like that. I see no reason why what you're doing shouldn't work. Are you having a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead I would prefer using `ng-href`

```
<a ng-href="{{getTitle()}}">link</a>
```

In your controller, return the `url` by checking logic there.

```
angular.module("app",[])
   .controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.book = {};
      $scope.book.title = null;
      $scope.book.category = {
        item : {
          title : "Rafi"
        }
      }
      $scope.getTitle = function() {
        return '#/'+ ($scope.book.title || $scope.book.category && $scope.book.category.item && $scope.book.category.item.title);
      }
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lawaba/1/edit)**

if you don't want to use controller for some reason:

```
 <a ng-href="{{'#/'+(book.title || book.category.item.title)}}">
```

Comment: book.title will be use if book.title is null